# What direction does the n vector (normal to the surface) have to be when doing Stokes' theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

The author uses $g=y+z-2$ instead of $g=2-y-z$ to ensure that n has a positive k component so that it points outward. But why was it necessary that n points outward? Is it because C is in the counter-clockwise and therefore positive direction? Or does it depend on the value of F?

Comment: Orientation; to get a real (rigorous) answer, however, you'll have to wait until you take differential geometry/topology.  A simple answer is what you've already indicated: the curve is oriented clockwise, and therefore the surface normal is outward (a physicist would tell you to apply the right-hand rule).  At the end of the day however, unless you're applying your result to other computations, it really doesn't matter since your answer will only differ by a sign.

Comment: It's because $C$ is counter-clockwise, as you said. If your normal vector points "up", then the "top" of the surface is the direction from which the parameterization of the border goes counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of the surface normal and the boundary need to agree; use the right hand rule on the oriented boundary to figure out which direction the surface normal needs to point.

Comment: If you are using a left-handed coordinate system, you must use the left hand rule.